# Adding a column based on counts of another column value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
comment_id <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
cat <- c("acc_sp", "acc_lex", "org_gen", "acc_gen", "ran_lex", "arg_rel", "len", "org_lay", "org_spe", "org_gen", "coh_link")
df <- data.frame(comment_id, cat)
```

You'll notice that there are two items with comment_id = 2.

I need to create a new column which uniquely numbers each iteration of a comment_id. The first five lines of the new column would be as follows:

| comment_cat_id |
| --- |
| 1_1 |
| 2_1 |
| 2_2 |
| 3_1 |
| 4_1 |

I'm thinking I can use:

```
df$comment_cat_id <- paste(comment_id, ?????, sep = "_")
```

to handle the creation of the new column. But I don't know how to generate the unique count of each occurrence of each comment_id to place into the ????? slot in the above code.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
comment_id <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
cat <- c("acc_sp", "acc_lex", "org_gen", "acc_gen", "ran_lex", "arg_rel", "len", "org_lay", "org_spe", "org_gen", "coh_link")
df <- data.frame(comment_id, cat)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(comment_cat_id = str_c(comment_id, row_number(), sep = "_"),
         .by = comment_id)
#>    comment_id      cat comment_cat_id
#> 1           1   acc_sp            1_1
#> 2           2  acc_lex            2_1
#> 3           2  org_gen            2_2
#> 4           3  acc_gen            3_1
#> 5           4  ran_lex            4_1
#> 6           5  arg_rel            5_1
#> 7           6      len            6_1
#> 8           7  org_lay            7_1
#> 9           8  org_spe            8_1
#> 10          9  org_gen            9_1
#> 11         10 coh_link           10_1
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, comment_id_cat := paste(comment_id, seq(.N), sep = "_"), by = comment_id][]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, you can use the 'ave' function, to solve the counting-problem.

```
    # your data
    comment_id <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    cat <- c("acc_sp", "acc_lex", "org_gen", "acc_gen", "ran_lex", "arg_rel", "len", "org_lay", "org_spe", "org_gen", "coh_link")
    df <- data.frame(comment_id, cat)
    
    # unique count for comment_id
    df$unique_count <- ave(df$comment_id, df$comment_id, FUN = seq_along)
    
    # Create the new column 
    df$comment_cat_id <- paste(df$comment_id, df$unique_count, sep = "_")
    
    # show
    head(df)

 comment_id     cat unique_count comment_cat_id
1          1  acc_sp            1            1_1
2          2 acc_lex            1            2_1
3          2 org_gen            2            2_2
4          3 acc_gen            1            3_1
5          4 ran_lex            1            4_1
6          5 arg_rel            1            5_1
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a way to do it.

```
df$newcol <- NA # New Column
freq <- as.data.frame(table(df$comment_id)) # Occurencies

> for (i in unique(df$comment_id)) {
+   df[df$comment_id == i,"newcol"] <- paste(i, 1:freq[freq$Var1 == i,"Freq"], sep="_") # For each id, it fills the new column
+ }
> df
  comment_id      cat newcol
1           1   acc_sp    1_1
2           2  acc_lex    2_1
3           2  org_gen    2_2
4           3  acc_gen    3_1
5           4  ran_lex    4_1
6           5  arg_rel    5_1
7           6      len    6_1
8           7  org_lay    7_1
9           8  org_spe    8_1
10          9  org_gen    9_1
11         10 coh_link   10_1
```